# JQuery - Searching a List of Objects for those Objects with a Particular Member Variable set to a Value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have a JS Object like:

```
{categories : [{id:1, name:"foo", items:[{id:1, name="bar"},{id:2,name:"baz"]}]}
```

Given the first category (index 0) and an item id, I would like to be able to find the item name.

In python, we could do something very clean like:

```
x.name for x in categories[0].items where x.id = 1
```

What is the cleanest and shortest way to express this in jQuery/JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method of `Array`:

`categories[0].items.filter( function(x){ return x.id == 1 });`

Edit after your edit:

to find the name of item where `x = 1`

`categories[0].items.filter( function(x){ return x.id == 1 })[0].name;`

if you know there's exactly one item or you only want the first one, or combining `.filter` with `.map` to get a list of names:

`categories[0].items.filter( function(x){ return x.id == 1 }).map( function(x){ return x.name })`

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6W2qa/1/

Comment: Great. I'll give you the answer regardless of course, but would you please demonstrate how to find the answer when you do not know which category you are selecting from? (I have to wait 2 minutes before awarding answer)

Comment: @MatthewMoisen you mean what if you don't know the category? I'd use `categories.forEach( function(cat){ /* get the name like in the example using cat.items.filter(...) */ })`